# XML Parsing with JSoup - access only the first result element

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jsoup, geocoding

I'm trying to use Google's geocoding API to access information about a specific address. When I make a request to the API for a specific address, it returns multiple Lat-Lng results, but I only want to choose the first one.

I am using JSoup to parse the document.

Here is some of the data in the xml result:

```
<GeocodeResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<result>
<geometry>
<location>
   <lat>53.3619592</lat>
   <lng>-6.2785289</lng>
</location>
<viewport>
<southwest>
   <lat>53.3606102</lat>
   <lng>-6.2798779</lng>
</southwest>
<northeast>
   <lat>53.3633082</lat>
   <lng>-6.2771799</lng>
</northeast>
</viewport>
</geometry>
</result>

<result>
<geometry>
<location>
   <lat>53.3725435</lat>
   <lng>-6.3210070</lng>
</location>
<viewport>
<southwest>
   <lat>53.3711945</lat>
   <lng>-6.3223560</lng>
</southwest>
<northeast>
   <lat>53.3738925</lat>
   <lng>-6.3196580</lng>
</northeast>
</viewport>
</geometry>
</result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

There are 7 of these "result" elements.

I am trying to print out the latlng location of the first result but I'm not exactly sure how to. Here's what I have so far with my java code:

```
String link = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Phibsborough,+Dublin,+Ireland,+CA&region=irl&key=vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
for (Element e : doc.select("result")) {
    System.out.println(e.select("lat"));
    System.out.println(e.select("lng"));
}
```

And it is printing out like this:

```
<lat>
  53.3619592
</lat>
<lat>
 53.3619592
</lat>
<lat>
 53.3619592
</lat>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
<lat>
  53.3619592
</lat>
<lat>
 53.3619592
</lat>
<lat>
 53.3619592
</lat>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
<lat>
  53.3619592
</lat>
<lat>
 53.3619592
</lat>
<lat>
 53.3619592
</lat>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
<lat>
  53.3619592
</lat>
<lat>
 53.3619592
</lat>
<lat>
 53.3619592
</lat>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
<lat>
  53.3619592
</lat>
<lat>
 53.3619592
</lat>
<lat>
 53.3619592
</lat>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
<lat>
  53.3619592
</lat>
<lat>
 53.3619592
</lat>
<lat>
 53.3619592
</lat>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
<lat>
  53.3619592
</lat>
<lat>
 53.3619592
</lat>
<lat>
 53.3619592
</lat>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
<lng>
 -6.2785289
</lng>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've correctly understood what you're trying to do, this should print lat / lng of the first element:

```
    String link = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Phibsborough,+Dublin,+Ireland,+CA&region=irl&key=";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();

    Elements elt = doc.getElementsByTag("location");  //get all elements for tag 'location'

    System.out.println(elt.get(0).text()); //get text from the first 'location' element
```

Which gives:  53.3599058 -6.2723999

To get them in String:

```
    String lat = elt.get(0).getElementsByTag("lat").get(0).text();
    String lng = elt.get(0).getElementsByTag("lng").get(0).text();
    System.out.println("lat: "+lat+"\tlng: "+lng);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use `first()` to get the first element from the selected Elements. Like this:

```
String link = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Phibsborough,+Dublin,+Ireland,+CA&region=irl&key=vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get(); 
Element e = doc.select("result").first()

System.out.println(e.select("lat"));
System.out.println(e.select("lng"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't parse the XML from the URI (I don't have an API key), so took your sample XML present in problem description and worked on it.

From your problem statement what I understood is that you are in need of Jsoup code, which gets the latitude and longitude data of the first result node.

I provide following solution:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class XMLParsingJsoup {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(
                new File("A:/Workspaces/MarsWorkspace/jSoupExample/src/main/resources/GeoLocationParser.xml"), "UTF-8");

        document.select("result:nth-of-type(1) lat, result:nth-of-type(1) lng").forEach(action -> { //Java 8 For Each
            System.out.println(action.text());
        });
    }
}
```

The output based upon your data is as follows,

```
53.3619592
-6.2785289
53.3606102
-6.2798779
53.3633082
-6.2771799
```

If you want the latitude and longitude to be printed separately, then split the css selector into two different select, instead of comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector need to be tuned like below to restrict to the first `result` node:

```
result:first-of-type
```

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
String link = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Phibsborough,+Dublin,+Ireland,+CA&region=irl&key=vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
Elements elts = doc.select("result:first-of-type"));
if (elts.isEmpty()) {
   // No results foud...
} else {
    Element firstResult = elts.first();
    System.out.println(firstResult.select("lat"));
    System.out.println(firstResult.select("lng"));
}
```